# office 365: design manager export -> import -> Create list ->Title column group becomes _hidden

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Using design manager >> export solution (Master Page/Page Layouts/Style library >> REST Code) >> generate WSP

Now, Import above WSP into another site collection >> Now create any list in this site. Title Column property Group="_Hidden" instead of "Custom Columns".

This is happening after first week of October-2016 in SharePoint Online(Office 365).

Any input will be appreciated!

-J

Answer (score 0):

https://mysponline.sharepoint.com/_vti_pvt/service.cnf

Previously:
 
vti_encoding:SR|utf8-nl
vti_extenderversion:SR|**16.0.0.5813**

Now,
vti_encoding:SR|utf8-nl
vti_extenderversion:SR|**16.0.0.5910**

and issue automatically resolved.

It might help to someone like me :)